# Access aws appsync api's environment specific table names in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I need to do some crud operation in the Dynamodb table which is used and created by Appsync API. I need to access it from a lambda function which I added by `amplify add function` command.  using the complete table name with API id and environment, as "User-apiid-dev" works fine. But, I don't want to hardcode the entire table name with environment name and API id in lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by using `API_UNDERDOGAMPLIFYAPI_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT` and `ENV`
 environment variables in the lambda function.

```
const UsersTable = `User-${process.env.API_UNDERDOGAMPLIFYAPI_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT}-${process.env.ENV}`
```

Comment: could you show your whole code how to get the data with imports and so? That would really help me. I have a similar problem.